# Why does a triangle have an interior angle of 180 degrees?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Every other regular polygon has 360, why is a triangle different?

Comment: Every regular polygon does not have a total interior angle of 360 degrees.

Comment: The sum of the interior angles charcterises the regular polygon. It is only $360^o$ for a square.

Comment: @RobArthan In my geometry class that was one of the things they taught us, is that incorrect?

Comment: @script8man You must misremember it. The sum of *exterior* angles is $360^\circ$ for any convex polygon (regular or not), including triangles.

Comment: @dxiv: so how does that work for an equilateral triangle with its $3$ exterior angles of $300^{o}$?

Comment: @RobArthan It is *exactly* $360^\circ$. See for example [Does the sum of exterior angles of a simple, convex polygon truly = 360°?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616520/does-the-sum-of-exterior-angles-of-a-simple-convex-polygon-truly-360). P.S. The exterior angle is defined as the supplement of the interior one. If you consider the sides of the polygon to be vectors oriented cyclically around the perimeter, an exterior angle is the angle between two consecutive such vectors.

Comment: @dxiv: it works if you read "exterior angle" as meaning the turn angle at each vertex as you traverse the edges of the polygon. That isn't how I would naturally interpret "exterior angle", but I think you are right in this context.

Comment: @RobArthan It's usually defined as the angle between a side and the line extended from the adjacent side (which amounts to the same measure as the "turn"), see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_and_external_angles) [or](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/exterior-angles.html) [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonexteriorangles.html).

Answer (score 3):

The dotted line through $C$ is parallel to $AB$.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant 'proofy' explanation.

Comment: Also foreshadows that if the parallel postulate does not hold, the angles of a triangles are not guaranteed to be 180°. For example, on a sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have triangle ABC. Draw a line, $l$, parallel to AB going through C. You will then see that the acute angle formed by $l$, A, and C will be equal to angle A, since they are alternate interior angles in parallel lines. The same can be said about the angle formed by $l$, B and C, which will be equal to angle B. Therefore, A+B+C must equal $180$ degrees.

Answer (score 1):

As @dxiv mentioned, the sum of exterior angles $\alpha_i$ of any *convex* polygon is $360^\circ$:

$$E = \sum_i \alpha_i = 360^\circ$$

You can justify this to yourself through a visual argument, as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616520/does-the-sum-of-exterior-angles-of-a-simple-convex-polygon-truly-360/1616526#1616526).

[image]

The complement of any exterior angle $\alpha_i$ is an interior angle of value $180^\circ - \alpha_i$. Since a triangle has three such exterior angles, the sum of its interior angles must be:

$$I = \sum_{i=1}^3 (180^\circ - \alpha_i)$$

Which can be rewritten:

$$I = 3\cdot 180^\circ - \sum_{i=1}^3 \alpha_i$$

Recalling the sum of exterior angles $E = \sum \alpha_i = 360^\circ$,

$$
\begin{align}
I &= 3\cdot 180^\circ - 360^\circ \\
  &= 180^\circ
\end{align}
$$

---

You can use this same argument to derive the general formula for convex polygons of $n$ sides:

$$
\begin{align}
I &= n\cdot 180^\circ - \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \\
  &= (n - 2) \cdot 180^\circ
\end{align}
$$